# Sort a pandas dataframe based on DateTime field

Tags: sorting, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sort a dataframe based on DateTime field which is of datatype datetime64[ns].

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Name    DateTime1
P38     NaT
P62     2016-07-13 16:03:32.771
P59     2016-06-23 14:23:42.461
P07     NaT
P16     2016-06-23 14:02:06.237
P06     2016-07-13 16:03:52.570
P106    2016-07-13 19:56:22.676
```

When I sort it using DateTime field,

```
df.sort_values(by='DateTime1',ascending=True)
```

I do not get the desired result.

Output:

```
Name    DateTime1
P16     2016-06-23 14:02:06.237
P59     2016-06-23 14:23:42.461
P62     2016-07-13 16:03:32.771
P06     2016-07-13 16:03:52.570
P106    2016-07-13 19:56:22.676
P38     NaT
P07     NaT
```

Comment: If your question is **solved**, please _**accept** the solution._ The **✔** is below the **▲/▼** arrow, at the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 36):

1. Try assigning back to `df`, otherwise use `inplace=True`, but don't do both. See [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

```py
df = df.sort_values(by='DateTime1', ascending=True)
```

2. Otherwise, try [`pandas.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

```py
df.set_index('DateTime1', drop=True, append=False, inplace=True, verify_integrity=False)
df = df.sort_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

For others who might find this useful. I got it working by using the inplace argument like so:

```
df.sort_values(by='DateTime1', ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I try both codes below but is not working

```
df = df.sort_values(by='DateTime1', ascending=True)
```

or

```
df.set_index('DateTime1', drop=True, append=False, inplace=True, verify_integrity=False)

df = df.sort_index()
```

What I found working is convert the datetime column to an index column and afterward sort by index. So in your case is:

```
df=df.set_index('DateTime1')       
                                            
df=df.sort_index(ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but OP seems to have wanted to put NaN values at the beginning since the output they posted is already sorted. In that case, there's a parameter in `sort_values` that controls where to put NaN values: `na_position`

```
df = df.sort_values(by='DateTime1', ascending=True, na_position='first')
```

Output:

```
   Name               DateTime1
0   P38                     NaT
3   P07                     NaT
4   P16 2016-06-23 14:02:06.237
2   P59 2016-06-23 14:23:42.461
1   P62 2016-07-13 16:03:32.771
5   P06 2016-07-13 16:03:52.570
6  P106 2016-07-13 19:56:22.676
```